# How much voltage does a farm electrical fence really output?

Tags: voltage, sensor, component-selection

My electrical fence control unit says that it outputs "0-miles 13 kV; 3-miles 7.0k; 5-miles 6.0k", yet that doesn't seem right.

Comment: if you followed the directions it is correct.  longer fence loads source with lower impedance

Comment: Is the 7kV measured at the end of the 3 miles, and is 6kV measured at the end of 5 miles, or is it measured at the source?

Answer (score 1):

1 mile of wire >1 foot above ground has roughly 10 nF of capacitance. The capacitance along with the output impedance of the device will attenuate the output voltage. There will also be leakage resistance from the insulators to ground which will further attenuate the voltage which depends on impurities on the insulator and humidity.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffU3Q0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Capacitance of a wire above ground is:

$$ C = {{2 \pi l \epsilon_o \epsilon_r} \over cosh^{-1} \left({h \over r} \right)} $$

Where:
\$ l \$ = length of wire in metres
\$ h \$ = high of wire above ground in metres
\$ r \$ = radius of wire in metres
\$ \epsilon_o \$ = permittivity of free space = 8.854e-12
\$ \epsilon_r \$ = relative permittivity (1 for air)

Graphing this for a 1 mile length (1609 m) of wire:

[image]

[Edit]
Crude attempt to model the electric fence in LTspice:

- A 10kHz half sine wave is used to model the voltage waveform of the device. A tear-down article of an electric fence shows a similar waveform with a faster rise time.
- Transformer winding loss and leakage inductance is modeled by R1 and L1. These values are guesses, but probably reasonable for a secondary with many turns.
- Device output capacitance is C1. Chosen to fit the desired outcome.
- Fence capacitance is C2 from the above calculation (10nF/mile).

[image]

Comment: How does that capacitance impact voltage at DC?

Comment: Not sure about his fence, but the ones I've seen have pulsed outputs

Comment: @ScottSeidman At DC, it stores more charge, but doesn't attenuate. As Wesley notes, electric fences for livestock used pulsed outputs, perhaps 1 pulse per second. One tearing apart article I saw, the output was about a 50us mostly uni-polarity pulse. I learned not to lean on horse pen fences when you hear a clicking noise nearby.

Comment: Townies quickly learn not to p*ss on electric fences - they touched it prior to tell me it was "off" - obviously between pulses :)

Comment: It seems like the original question was asking if 13KV for 0 miles of fencing, 7KV for 3 miles of fencing, and 6KV for 5 miles of fencing made sense together.  You provided a circuit model, but I don't see any attempt to try and calculate if the numbers are consistent with each other.

Comment: @user4574 The OP didn't give enough information. What is needed is the output complex impedance, pulse shape, output components in the device, ... All I can say is the output voltage reducing in amplitude with increasing wire length makes sense due to capacitive loading.

Comment: @user4574 I added a simulation. Lots of guesses involved.

Answer (score -1):

13KV is the unloaded (open-circuit) voltage.

Lets assume that the source has some unknown source resistance R1.
Lets also assume that 3 miles of fencing loads down the source with R2.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fX1L6V.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

We know that...

$$13kV * \frac{R_2}{R_2+R_1} = 7kV$$

Rearranging gives...

$$ R_2 =  \frac{7}{6} R_1$$

Lets add in another 2 miles of fencing (to make 5 total).  Lets call it R3.  As an approximation we might expect the extra two miles to be 3/2 as much resistance as 3 miles, so...

$$ R3 = \frac 3 2 * \frac 7 6 * R_1 = \frac {7}{4} R_1$$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fR1Xvg.png)</sup>

Doing the math here gives...
$$5.35KV = 13kV * \frac {0.7R1}{1.7R1}$$

Note that this is not that far off from 6kV.  So, the 6kV quoted by the manufacturer is plausible.  To get an exact answer we would probably need to do some integrals and I don't have time for that right now.

Comment: Why are you sure the extra fence is in parallel?

Comment: Parallel or series makes little difference since the wire resistance is relatively low (90 ohms/km for 16 gauge wire).

Comment: @ScottSeidman The load resistances are both leakage to ground.  I neglected the wire resistance in the model since its probably negligible.  In that case both loads look like they are in parallel.